# Install sonata bundle with PHP7

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install sonata with PHP7 in windows, but no luck. I don't have composer.phar

Steps:
1. php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"

2. php symfony new my_project 2.8
3. composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle
4. composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
   I had compatibility issue so that, I repeat 3 and 4 after step 5
5. php composer.phar require "sensio/generator-bundle"   "~2.3" --dev

Update app/kernel.php
            `new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),`

Update app/config/config.yml

```
sonata_block:
default_contexts: [cms]
blocks:
    # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
        contexts: [admin]
```

Update app/config/routing.yml

```
admin_area:
resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
prefix: /admin
```

At last:

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console assets:install
```

But, I can't see my admin in the browser.

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*"
```

Comment: What you mean by you *can't* see?  What url are you trying to access? Do you get any error?

Comment: my project name is demo.  I tried to run admin using http://localhost/demo/web/admin  But, I am getting The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Comment: is it apache's error page or symfony's?

Comment: It's symfony error. As http://localhost/demo/web/ is working fine.

Comment: `localhost/demo/web` working fine doesn't mean anything. Are you sure it's Symfony's page? it should have Symfony logo etc. Or does it look like this: http://www.glenncrocker.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/apache-404.png ?

Comment: I don't know how I check either error, I posted all the things here what I know.

Comment: Just check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled in Apache's config file.

Comment: <Directory />  
    AllowOverride none  
    Require all denied  
</Directory>  **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** is uncomment in my apache config file

Comment: Here's example configuration of apache. http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi   It should be `AllowOverride All` `Order Allow,Deny`  `Allow from All`

Comment: in **app/.htaccess**, I have all the above modes